# How do I start many ring subprojects with a single lein task?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I have a project with three subprojects like so (using [lein-sub](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-sub)):

```
(defproject trident "0.1.0"
  ...

  :sub
  ["admin"
   "api"
   "site"])
```

Each has a ring handler inside, something like this:

```
(defproject trident-api "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  ...

  :ring {:handler trident.api.core/handler
         :servlet-name "trident-api"
         :init trident.api.core/init
         :port 33333})
```

Right now I go into each and type:

```
> lein ring server
```

This obviously gets tiresome.  I also tried

```
> lein sub ring server
```

Which seems like it should work, but it only starts the first one and the process joins it!  Possibly there is a way around that?  It seems like this would be the simplest approach.

In lieu of that, I am now writing a leiningen task to do this for me, but am running into some issues.  I can get the project file for each easily enough using leiningen.core.project/read, but from here, how do I start each ring server in a way that honors all of the dependencies and other settings from their respective project.clj files?

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? I imagine the lein-sub code would be a good place to start.

Comment: I have gone through the code, it is very simple.  The only issue is how do I keep the process from joining the first two jetty's that get created, while still allowing them to run?

Comment: lein sub doesn't seem to change the working directory whereas you seem to do a "cd submodule; lein ring server".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a metaserver to start all three jetty instances at once.  Code is here:

https://github.com/antler/lein-caribou/blob/master/src/leiningen/caribou/server.clj

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, as I am not able to verify if this will work right now.

[There is a var](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L24) in `leiningen.core.project` that identifies default values. Maybe you could write a plugin (or fork lein-sub?) and have it override these values for the sub project? Then you can create a plugin that iterates over each sub project while applying a given task to each one.

For example, the defaults declares the source path like so:

```
:source-paths ["src"]
```

You could then override it with the following for each sub project:

```
:source-paths ["sub-project/src"]
```

Do that with all the pertinent defaults, and it might just work.

There might be a way to do this with Leiningen 2's profiles, but I'm not sure. I imagine if you create a profile for each sub project in the parent project, you could easily merge the profile when invoking the task on the respective sub project.